# Copying one table to another plus one column dependant of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

NAME and VER are the primary keys.
Instead of writing down what I am trying to do, I will draw.

Table origin:

```
NAME | SOMETHING1 | VER | SOMETHING2 | MODDATIME
john | bob        | 1   | doe        | 18-AUG-14 10.16.08.695221100 AM
john | bob        | 2   | doe        | 19-AUG-14 11.01.42.109826000 AM
john | bob        | 3   | doe        | 09-SEP-14 10.14.15.929342100 AM
john | bob        | 4   | doe        | 10-SEP-14 10.14.15.929342100 AM
```

Table target:

```
NAME | SOMETHING1 | VER | SOMETHING2 | MODDATIME                       | DATEUP
john | bob        | 1   | doe        | 18-AUG-14 10.16.08.695221100 AM | 19-AUG-14 11.01.42.109826000 AM
john | bob        | 2   | doe        | 19-AUG-14 11.01.42.109826000 AM | 09-SEP-14 10.14.15.929342100 AM
john | bob        | 3   | doe        | 09-SEP-14 10.14.15.929342100 AM | 10-SEP-14 10.14.15.929342100 AM
john | bob        | 4   | doe        | 10-SEP-14 10.14.15.929342100 AM | 31-DEC-99 0.0.0.0 AM
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Table target is empty. Only columns are setup. I want to copy table origin to table target but with the specific trick with DATEUP.

Comment: The "specific trick" is not that obvious as you think. For me, `DATEUP` looks like random data.

Comment: It is not random data, it is from MODDATIME of the next entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `OUTER JOIN` with the same Table to get the result

```
SELECT a.NAME,
       a.something,
       a.VER,
       a.something,
       a.MODDATIME,
       Ifnull(b.MODDATIME,'31-DEC-99 0.0.0.0 AM') AS DateUP
FROM   Yourtable a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Yourtable b
              ON a.NAME = b.NAME
                 AND a.VER = b.VER - 1
```

Comment: This assumes the values in the `VER` column are consecutive, without any gap.

Comment: There is (null) within DATUP column. Also I need insert to at a point to put entries in target table.

Comment: @Bebeoix - Yeah last row will be null. you can use `IFNULL` to get the default date or last date